# Logarithm of the Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, cumulants

I've [found this paper on the logarithm of the discrete fourier transform](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/2007/20682.pdf) which proves that

$$
log F = 1/4 i \pi (I - (1 +i)F + F^2 - (1 - i)F^3)
$$

where $F$ is the unitary discrete Fourier transform operator.

Is there a similar analogous version known for the infinite dimensional Fourier transform?

I am asking this from the point of view of trying to better understand [cumulants](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/2007/20682.pdf), whose generating function is the logarithm of the characteristic function. The characteristic function is the fourier transform of the PDF of a random variable, thus motivating this question.

EDIT: Please take as many "niceness" assumptions as needed to answer the question regarding convergence.

Comment: First one has to worry about convergence of the logarithm in the infinite-dimensional setting ….

Comment: [The spectrum of the Fourier transform on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765380/spectrum-of-the-fourier-transform-operator), so it should suffice to choose any polynomial which agrees with (your favorite branch of) the complex logarithm on those four points.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm _really_ unfamiliar with the "proper" fourier transform. I've only used it from a "physics" standpoint. Could you please expand your comment into an answer, as I do not really understand what you've  said? That would be very helpful for me :)

Comment: Reading your question again, though, I think you may be mixing up two different things.  The cumulant is the log of the Fourier transform of a specific function.   But the paper you link, and my comment, are about taking the log of the Fourier transform *operator* in the sense of spectral theory.  It's the difference between $\log(F[f])$ and $(\log F)[f]$.  It's like the fact that if $A$ is a matrix and $v$ is a vector, $A^2 v$ is not the same as taking $Av$ and squaring each entry.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with the identity $F^4=I$. As a result, we have formally
\begin{align}
\ln F&=\ln(I+F-I)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(F-I)^k}{k}
\\&=
\sum_{1\le k\le 3}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(F-I)^k}{k}+
\sum_{k\ge 4}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{0\le l\le 3}\binom{k}{l} F^l(-1)^{k-l}
\\&\hskip94pt+
\sum_{k\ge 4}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{k\ge l\ge 4}\binom{k}{l} F^l(-1)^{k-l},
\end{align}
and since in the last sum $F^l=F^j$ with $j\equiv l\mod 4$, we get a polynomial in $F$ with degree 3, that is
$$
\ln F= a_0+a_1 F+a_2 F^2
+a_3 F^3.$$
I guess that it is straightforward to get the expressions of the $a_j$ from the above identity. Also you can use the fonction $g(x)=e^{-π x^2}$ which is such that $(F-I) g=0$ implying that
$$
0=(\ln F)(g)=(a_0+a_1 +a_2 
+a_3)(g)\Longrightarrow \sum_{0\le j\le 3}a_j=0,
$$
and in fine you will get the same coefficients as yours.

Answer (score 0):

$$F=e^{\frac{1}{4} \pi  i \left(D^2-x^2+1\right)}$$

This is for unitary case.

Comment: Your operator doesn't converge for most kind of functions.

Answer (score 0):

For $F$ any linear map such that $F^4=Id$ then  $F=  \sum_{k=0}^3 i^k  T_k$ where $T_k =\frac14 \sum_{m=0}^3 i^{-mk} F^m $, $T_k^2=T_k,T_k T_l = 0$ which gives that $(\sum_{k=0}^3 c_k  T_k)^n = \sum_{k=0}^3 c_k^n  T_k$.

With $L=\sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{ki\pi}{2} T_k$ we get that $\exp(L)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{(\frac{ki\pi}{2})^n}{n!}  T_k=\sum_{k=0}^3 \exp(\frac{ki\pi}{2}) T_k= F$.